# Laravel: how to separate cache and session into different redis database?

Tags: php, caching, laravel

I want to put session and cache data into redis. This is my configuration in database.php:

```
'redis' => array(

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => array(
        'host'     => '192.168.56.101',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ),

    'session' => array(
        'host'     => '192.168.56.101',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 1,
    ),
),
```

session.php:

```
return array(
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'connection' => 'session',
);
```

cache.php:

```
'driver' => 'redis',
```

However, where I write code like this:

```
Cache::remember('aa',1,function(){
    return 'bb';
});
```

cache driver uses the same redis database as session driver does, which results in:

```
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> keys *
1) "aa"
2) "e0606244bec40b0352fb2b7b65d98049e49f6189"
```

Anyone knows how to force cache to use a specific redis connection? Or I have to mix them up together?

Answer (score 9):

### Introduction

Here is my note, for some other guy who running in to this problem, I think this is should be in the docs.

By default, redis gives you 16 separate databases, but laravel out of the box will try to use database 0 for both sessions and cache.

Our solution is to let Redis caching using database 0, and database 1 for Session, there for solving the session clear by running `php artisan cache:clear` problem.

> Note: Tested at Laravel 5.1

### 1. Setting up Session Redis connection

Modify `config/database.php`, add `session` key to the `redis` option:

```
'redis' => [

   'cluster' => false,

   'default' => [
       'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
       'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
       'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
       'database' => 0,
   ],

   'session' => [
         'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
         'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
         'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
         'database' => 1,
   ],
],
```

#### 2. Make use of the `session` connection

Modify `config/session.php`, change the following:

```
'connection' => null,
```

to:

```
'connection' => 'session',
```

#### 3. Using Redis as session driver

Modify `.env`, change `SESSION_DRIVER`:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
```

#### 4. Testing out

Execute the following artisan command, then check your login state:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

If the login state persists, voilà!

Answer (score 5):

Laravel 5.5:

database.php should look like this:

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

    'session' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 1,
    ],

],
```

And in the session.php you have to update also the key "connection" to the right key. In this case 'session'

```
'connection' => 'session',
```

Answer (score 3):

**Laravel 5** now supports this.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/d10a840514d122fa638eb5baa24c8eae4818da3e

You can select redis connection by modifying `config/cache.php`

```
'stores' => [
    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'your-connection-name',
    ],
],
```

---

Laravel 4 `CacheManager` does not support selecting redis connection.

What you need to do is to modify/extend `CacheManager` and override `createRedisDriver()` method.

Modify this line

```
return $this->repository(new RedisStore($redis, $this->getPrefix()));
```

To

```
return $this->repository(
    new RedisStore($redis, $this->getPrefix(), 
    $this->app['config']['cache.redis'])
);
```

Now you can define your configuration in cache.php

```
'redis' => 'your-connection-name'
```

Comment: Thank you,but it doesn't work.Session's redis driver reuses the redis connection created by CacheManager.So this modification still results in sessions and caches mixed up together.

Comment: Did you create and reference a new redis connection?